# Why does Java have an IINC bytecode instruction?

Tags: java, bytecode

Why does Java have an `IINC` bytecode instruction?
There is already an `IADD` bytecode instruction that can be used to accomplish the same.

So why does `IINC` exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only the original designers of Java can answer why they made particular design decisions. However, we can speculate:

`IINC` does not let you do anything that can't already be accomplished by a `ILOAD`/`SIPUSH`/`IADD`/`ISTORE` combo. The difference is that `IINC` is a single instruction, which only takes 3 or 6 bytes, while the 4 instruction sequence is obviously longer. So `IINC` slightly reduces the size of bytecode that uses it.

Apart from that, early versions of Java used an interpreter, where every instruction has overhead during execution. In this case, using a single `IINC` instruction could be faster than the equivalent alternative bytecode sequence. Note that JITting has made this largely irrelevant, but `IINC` dates back to the original version of Java.

Comment: For what it's worth, the Java 8 compiler still uses this instruction.

Answer (score 3):

As [already pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37063022/2711488) a single `iinc` instruction is shorter than the a `iload`, `sipush`, `iadd`, `istore` sequence. There is also evidence, that performing a common-case code size reduction was an important motivation.

There are specialized instructions for dealing with the first four local variables, e.g. `aload_0` does the same as `aload 0` and it will be used often for loading the `this` reference on the operand stack. There’s an `ldc` instruction being able to refer to one of the first 255 constant pool items whereas all of them could be handled by `ldc_w`, branch instructions use two bytes for offsets, so only overly large methods have to resort to `goto_w`, and `iconst_n` instructions for `-1` to `5` exist despite these all could be handled by `bipush` which supports values which all also could all be handled by `sipush`, which could be superseded by `ldc`.

So asymmetric instructions are the norm. In typical applications, there are a lot of small methods with only a few local variables and smaller numbers are more common than larger numbers. `iinc` is a direct equivalent to stand-alone `i++` or `i+=smallConstantNumber` expressions (applied to local variables) which often occur within loops. By being able to express common code idioms in more compact code without loosing the ability to express all code, you’ll get great savings in overall code size.

As also already pointed out, there is only a slight opportunity for faster execution in interpreted executions which is irrelevant for compiled/optimized code execution.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings), there are a couple important differences.

> iinc: increment local variable #index by signed byte const

1. `iinc` uses a [register](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_registers.htm) instead of the stack.
2. `iinc` can only increment by a *signed* byte value. If you want to add `[-128,127]` to an integer, then you could use `iinc`, but as soon as you want to add a number outside that range you would need to use `isub`, `iadd`, or multiple `iinc` instructions.

---

E1:

## TL;DR

I was basically right, except that the limit is signed short values (16 bits `[-32768,32767]`). There's a `wide` bytecode instruction which modifies `iinc` (and a couple other instructions) to use 16 bit numbers instead of 8 bit numbers.

Additionally, consider adding two variables together. If one of the variables is not constant, the compiler will never be able to inline its value to bytecode, so it cannot use `iinc`; it will have to use `iadd`.

---

```
package SO37056714;

public class IntegerIncrementTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 1;
    i += 5;
  }
}
```

I'm going to be experimenting with the above piece of code. As it is, is uses `iinc`, as expected.

```
$ javap -c IntegerIncrementTest.class 
Compiled from "IntegerIncrementTest.java"
public class SO37056714.IntegerIncrementTest {
  public SO37056714.IntegerIncrementTest();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #8                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: iconst_1
       1: istore_1
       2: iinc          1, 5
       5: return
}
```

`i += 127` uses `iinc` as expected.

```
$ javap -c IntegerIncrementTest.class 
Compiled from "IntegerIncrementTest.java"
public class SO37056714.IntegerIncrementTest {
  public SO37056714.IntegerIncrementTest();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #8                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: iconst_1
       1: istore_1
       2: iinc          1, 127
       5: return
}
```

`i += 128` does not use `iinc` anymore, but instead `iinc_w`:

```
$ javap -c IntegerIncrementTest.class 
Compiled from "IntegerIncrementTest.java"
public class SO37056714.IntegerIncrementTest {
  public SO37056714.IntegerIncrementTest();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #8                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: iconst_1
       1: istore_1
       2: iinc_w        1, 128
       8: return
}
```

`i -= 601` also uses `iinc_w`:

```
$ javap -c IntegerIncrementTest.class 
Compiled from "IntegerIncrementTest.java"
public class SO37056714.IntegerIncrementTest {
  public SO37056714.IntegerIncrementTest();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #8                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: iconst_1
       1: istore_1
       2: iinc_w        1, -601
       8: return
}
```

The `_w` suffix refers to the `wide` bytecode, which allows for constants up to 16 bits (`[-32768, 32767]`).

If we try `i += 32768`, we will see what I predicted above:

```
$ javap -c IntegerIncrementTest.class 
Compiled from "IntegerIncrementTest.java"
public class SO37056714.IntegerIncrementTest {
  public SO37056714.IntegerIncrementTest();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #8                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: iconst_1
       1: istore_1
       2: iload_1
       3: ldc           #16                 // int 32768
       5: iadd
       6: istore_1
       7: return
}
```

Additionally, consider the case where we are adding another variable to `i` (`i += c`). The compiler doesn't know if `c` is constant or not, so it cannot inline `c`'s value to bytecode. It will use `iadd` for this case too:

```
int i = 1;
byte c = 3;
i += c;
```

```
$ javap -c IntegerIncrementTest.class 
Compiled from "IntegerIncrementTest.java"
public class SO37056714.IntegerIncrementTest {
  public SO37056714.IntegerIncrementTest();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #8                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: iconst_1
       1: istore_1
       2: iconst_3
       3: istore_2
       4: iload_1
       5: iload_2
       6: iadd
       7: istore_1
       8: return
}
```

Comment: I get your first point, but I don't think your second point is right.
Because I just saw this: "iinc 14 -601"

Comment: @Jeffrey Oracle's JVM is not register based and are instead stored on the stack. Also you somewhat alluded to it, but it might be worth explicitly mentioning the drastic size differences between the forms.